# How to remove unwanted margin

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a HTML list that and separate them by column-width. But there is a space between each column that I don't know how to remove.  It seems inaccessible to me. I want it to be like rows which does not have any space or at least I choose the size of the space.

this is my ul code

```
ul {
height:400px;
background-color:#666;
list-style-type: none;
-webkit-column-width:200px;
}
```

And this is demo:http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKR/3/

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your CSS

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

Some browsers will still display some margin around certain block level elements. If your margins are still showing add a float value to it.

Comment: Didn't see your demo. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the UL style.

```
-webkit-column-gap:0px;
```

Comment: `-webkit` prefixed styles only target Safari and Chrome. It won't help with Firefox or IE. (And the issue is present, to a smaller degree, in Firefox.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas also, Chrome is moving to Blink so this sort of stuff should be avoided anyway.

Comment: Hi Roddy, I assumed because he is already using Webkit only styles, I should keep with it :)

Answer (score 0):

And one trick more (not sure if it will work in all browsers):

http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKR/12/

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:220px;
    height:180px;
    padding:10px -10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;

}
```

webkit-column-width should be removed in order to work properly in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

may i sure try this

http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKR/3/

CSS

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:220px;
    height:180px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;

}
```